# Android SQLite3: alter table not working in OnUpdate

Tags: android, sqlite

I am doing an `alter table entry add column logdate date` in sqlite using `SQLiteOpenHelper`'s `onUpdate` call.
After altering, I can see that my table is having the column which was created through the alter script (through `sqlite3 /data/data/mypackage/databases/mydb.db`).

Although I am getting this weird error `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column 'logdate' does not exist` while selecting the column for listing (internally using `CursorLoader` and `SimpleCursorAdapter`)

The `SQLiteOpenHelper` implementation is as follows:

```
public static void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
    Log.i("DB", "Creating table: " + TABLE_NAME);
    database.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_SQL);
}
public static void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    Log.i("DB", "updating database from v" + oldVersion + " to v" + newVersion);
    for (int upgradeTo = oldVersion + 1; upgradeTo <= newVersion; upgradeTo++) {
        Log.d("DB", "incremental database update from v" + (upgradeTo - 1) + " to v" + upgradeTo);
        switch (newVersion) {
            case 1: 
                onCreate(database);
                break;
            case 2:
                alterTable(database, "add column " + COLUMN_DATE + " date default 0;");
                break;
        }
    }
}
private static void alterTable(SQLiteDatabase database, String alterAdditions) {
    String sql = "alter table " + TABLE_NAME + " " + alterAdditions;
    Log.v("DB", "alter script: " + sql);
    database.execSQL(sql);
}
```

I have done a background search on SQLite3 alter table scripts, and [here](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html) it says that the database will not be readable if `ADD COLUMN` is used. Is this a bug that I'm seeing or something wrong with my code?

EDIT#1:

Logcat(slightly modified)

```
01-08 21:43:47.381: D/AndroidRuntime(6607): Shutting down VM
01-08 21:43:47.381: E/AndroidRuntime(6607): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-08 21:43:47.381: E/AndroidRuntime(6607): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column 'logdate' does not exist
01-08 21:43:47.381: E/AndroidRuntime(6607):     at android.database.AbstractCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(AbstractCursor.java:303)
01-08 21:43:47.381: E/AndroidRuntime(6607):     at android.database.CursorWrapper.getColumnIndexOrThrow(CursorWrapper.java:78)
01-08 21:43:47.381: E/AndroidRuntime(6607):     at android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter.findColumns(SimpleCursorAdapter.java:333)
01-08 21:43:47.381: E/AndroidRuntime(6607):     at android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter.swapCursor(SimpleCursorAdapter.java:345)
01-08 21:43:47.381: E/AndroidRuntime(6607):     at my.app.package.OverviewFragment.onLoadFinished(OverviewFragment.java:118)
01-08 21:43:47.381: E/AndroidRuntime(6607):     at my.app.package.OverviewFragment.onLoadFinished(OverviewFragment.java:1)
01-08 21:43:47.381: E/AndroidRuntime(6607):     at android.app.LoaderManagerImpl$LoaderInfo.callOnLoadFinished(LoaderManager.java:483)
01-08 21:43:47.381: E/AndroidRuntime(6607):     at android.app.LoaderManagerImpl$LoaderInfo.onLoadComplete(LoaderManager.java:451)
01-08 21:43:47.381: E/AndroidRuntime(6607):     at android.content.Loader.deliverResult(Loader.java:143)
01-08 21:43:47.381: E/AndroidRuntime(6607):     at android.content.CursorLoader.deliverResult(CursorLoader.java:113)
01-08 21:43:47.381: E/AndroidRuntime(6607):     at android.content.CursorLoader.deliverResult(CursorLoader.java:43)
01-08 21:43:47.381: E/AndroidRuntime(6607):     at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader.dispatchOnLoadComplete(AsyncTaskLoader.java:254)
01-08 21:43:47.381: E/AndroidRuntime(6607):     at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.onPostExecute(AsyncTaskLoader.java:91)
01-08 21:43:47.381: E/AndroidRuntime(6607):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
01-08 21:43:47.381: E/AndroidRuntime(6607):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
01-08 21:43:47.381: E/AndroidRuntime(6607):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
01-08 21:43:47.381: E/AndroidRuntime(6607):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-08 21:43:47.381: E/AndroidRuntime(6607):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-08 21:43:47.381: E/AndroidRuntime(6607):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5227)
01-08 21:43:47.381: E/AndroidRuntime(6607):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-08 21:43:47.381: E/AndroidRuntime(6607):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-08 21:43:47.381: E/AndroidRuntime(6607):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
01-08 21:43:47.381: E/AndroidRuntime(6607):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
01-08 21:43:47.381: E/AndroidRuntime(6607):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: post log from upgrade and stacktrace.

Comment: Do you have multiple instances of your SQLiteOpenHelper implementation?

Comment: That documentation page talks about SQLite version 3.1.3 or earlier.

Comment: The error that you get tells that the due to some reasons that column doesn't exists. Download `sqlitebrowser_200_b1_win` and the pull the database from your device/emulator and check if the column does exists. If so, then that might be multiple instance problem.

Comment: @RohanKandwal the column exists, BTW the file will not run on my system, using linux here. Also i have a rooted phone which i used to check the database. The column is there, as I mentioned in the question

Comment: @njzk2 I have added the logcat output (slightly modified).

Comment: @beworker, there is only one instance of it, created while creating the ContentProvider.

Comment: @CL yes, I also thought that after posting the question. sqlite3 version is shown to be `3.7.11 2012-03-20 11:35:50 00bb9c9ce4f465e6ac321ced2a9d0062dc364669`.

Comment: Ok, found the issue, the projection was wrong. Thank you all for the replies. Sorry for the noob mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Delete your old version of database from terminal

```
adb shell
cd /data/data/com.example.applicationname/databases
rm *
```

Comment: hi, this issue has been solved. as i said in the comments of OP http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20999915/android-sqlite3-alter-table-not-working-in-onupdate/21155000?noredirect=1#comment31560901_20999915
It was a coding error.